# How to display array elements in UITextField in swift 3?

Tags: arrays, swift, casting, uitextfield

I want to display the button.tag value in UITextField. For that I append the tapped button value in array. I initialized the array on top as

```
var inputString:Array = [String]()
```

Now I tried to put these array values in UITextField like this

```
        self.txtPassword.text = self.inputString
```

I tried this as I did earlier in objective c. But in swift I am unable to do this. Please someone give me solution. Thanks

Comment: Can you show your Objective-C code, and perhaps a sample of what you expect the value of the text field to be?

Comment: just `inputString.joined()` or `inputString.joined(withSeparator: ", ")`

Comment: This is my objective - c code
    [self.inputPassowrd appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)button.tag]];

    self.txtPassword.text = self.inputPassowrd;

Comment: Thank you so much. .joined() worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to attribute an array to a String. That will never work.

If you need one value of the array to be attributed to the textField, you need to know its index and do:

```
self.txtPassword.text = self.inputString[index]
```